# I'm trying to update latst record based on id in laravel but it is showing issue like Call to a member function latest() on int

Tags: laravel-8

```
DB::table('task_tracker')
->where('task_id', $task_id)
->update([
   'task_status'=> 'Paused',
   'task_finished_at'=> $finished_at,
   'action_comment'=>'Task Paused'
])
->latest()
->first();
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you are calling `->latest()` on an integer.  If you look at your code, that makes sense. `update()` will do an update, my guess is it will return true/false, or maybe the number of records updated, right?  Which is exactly what your error says ...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551397/laravel-dbupdate-only-return-0-or-1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093965/return-collection-after-update, ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return Collection after update()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093965/return-collection-after-update)

Answer (score 0):

update return 1 or 0;

```
DB::table('task_tracker')
->where('task_id', $task_id)
->latest()
->update([
   'task_status'=> 'Paused',
   'task_finished_at'=> $finished_at,
   'action_comment'=>'Task Paused'
])
->first();
```

Try this it may work